# In typescript Callback function

Tags: typescript

This is my code in typescript

```
function loginWithPassword(user: Object | string, password: string, callback?: Function): void;
```

I did not know what's happening on this code in typescript

Answer (score 3):

this is the signature definition of function `loginWithPassword`.

Let's break down this code:

```
function loginWithPassword(
    user: Object | string, 
    password: string, 
    callback?: Function): void;
```

> defining that `loginWithPassword` is a `function` which will return `void`
>      
> It will accept `three parameters`:
>      
>  1st param `user` will be of type `object or a string`
>      
>  2nd param `password` will always be a `string`
>      
>  3rd param `callback` will be a `function`

Comment: But my login functionality is happening here only......... that means this function only refer the database for the given parameters

Comment: @Sujitha what you see is only the *type definition*, or in other term, the *signature* of a function. It defines the type of inputs this function takes, and the type of output it returns. However, nothing really "happens" in this line of code, that part sits in the *implementation* of this *type definition*, which you did not show in OP.

Comment: Hi Ashish....Thanks for ur rply actually loginWithPassword() is the inbuilt function in meteor.....Thanks for ur explanation..